# Rest API expand folder then get column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a rest api right now that accesses files in a folder. It works and returns the name of the file and a count accurately. I am trying to get data from a column field as well but everything I've done returns as undefined. I have my code cycling through files in the folder and all I need is to get the FileType field for each item.

```
"/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + folderUrl + "')?$expand=Folders,Files&$select=fileType",
```

Comment: Is `fileType` a custom column that you added, or a default column?

Comment: custom column that is a choice field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you are trying to do two things at once:

- Get the Item Count for the given folder
- Get the 'fileType' column for all items in the folder

This seems like a job better suited to multiple sequential REST calls, but this worked for me:

```
<server>/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Pages')?$expand=Folders,Files/ListItemAllFields/FieldValuesAsText&$select=ItemCount,Folders/ItemCount,Folders/Name,Files/ListItemAllFields/FieldValuesAsText/File_x005f_x0020_x005f_Type,Files/ListItemAllFields/FieldValuesAsText/fileLeafRef
```

Here I'm doing multiple levels of expansion and selection:

`$expand=Folders,Files/ListItemAllFields/FieldValuesAsText`

- The additional expansion on Files was just to get to the `File_x005f_x0020_x005f_Type` value for each file, which is the same as the file extension

`$select=ItemCount,Folders/ItemCount,Folders/Name,Files/ListItemAllFields/FieldValuesAsText/File_x005f_x0020_x005f_Type,Files/ListItemAllFields/FieldValuesAsText/fileLeafRef`

- This selects `ItemCount` for the current folder (the folder you specified in `GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl`), `ItemCount` and `Name` for each sub-folder, and `File_x005f_x0020_x005f_Type` and `fileLeafRef` (the literal file name) for all files contained in the current folder, regardless of sub-folders.

Since this query goes several levels deep, it returns a lot of metadata that you probably don't need. So I would recommend using the `odata=nometadata` headers when making your REST call:

`Accept:application/json;odata=nometadata
Content-Type:application/json;odata=nometadata`

Edit: If I recall correctly, the `nometadata` property only works with SP 2016+

Comment: still seems to be returning undefined, the column name in Sharepoint is FileType, Do i need '_x005f_x0020_x005f_' ?

Comment: I'm not sure. Try running the query without the $select clause. It should return the full set of columns for each file, then you can find the ones you need. Also, if you're not already, I would suggest using a REST app like Postman* to explore the API.

*I have no affiliation, it's just the one I use.

Comment: running without the select clause worked! thanks!